# Optional chaining unwrapping error

Tags: swift

```
class Ppl{
    var residence:Residence?
}
class Residence{
    var addr="Default place"
}
var ppl=Ppl()
ppl.residence!=Residence() 

// I put a unexpected exclamation mark after residence
// until now it should return no error but if I put below line

var someaddr=ppl.residence?.addr
```

> error: Excution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0).

Comment: What's your question? `ppl.residence!` will crash because `ppl.residence` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ppl` has an instance of `Ppl` because you have created an instance with this `var ppl=Ppl()`. But inside the implementation of `Ppl` you have declared `residence` as an optional variable without creating an instance. So when you access `ppl.residence!` (with an exclamation) mark, the optional is unwrapped first. This gives you a nil value even before you assign it an instance of `Residence`. Just replace that line with `ppl.residence = Residence()` and it will work fine.

Comment: yeah you are right, as simple as that, I was confused, I should not put optional to a already unwrapped value

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `ppl.residence!=Residence()` with `ppl.residence = Residence()`.